# How to hang lights from vinyl siding?

Tags: lighting, outdoor, hanging

I have a couple of townhomes that I want to run some industrial outdoor string lighting - thick gauge.   The problem is there is nothing except the house to hang these from.   As I get into the yard I will have to install something to hold them - but that is another question.

What are some options of hanging the lights from the house without damaging the siding too much and for sure not creating a place for water to get into?

(I know that pictures would help but they wouldn't... this property has literally has a walkout door and 20 foot high brick of vinyl siding.   There are no poles or anything else.)

[image]

Comment: Install permanent connectors on the vertical studs behind the siding. The connectors should be rust-free type, and you need to seal around the siding penetration to prevent water/moisture from entering.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to anchor to the wall studs. They are behind the siding and whatever they covered the studs with, there are a lot of possible materials they could have used. I am assuming 3/8" by 3" eye bolts will do the job. When you install them place with a small upward angel to keep water away from the hole. You will need a good stud finder. I drill a small hole, just big enough to pass a piece of coat hanger wire through.  I do this to be sure I hit a stud and not an open area. If you miss it is small enough a little bit of calk will fill it.

Comment: Seems to me that a 3/8 x 3" bolt is going to be a bit overkill to hang some lights from, but, it may be necessary. I think the most important part, once the bolt has been chosen, is to put a fair bit of silicone around the top threads, near the eye, when installing, to make a nice seal to prevent water ingress.

Comment: When you start drill a small hole through the siding, trim etc until you reach the framing wood. From that you can determine your bolt length, you probably want about 1" into the wood, the siding etc will not hold. I gave that measurement because I have no idea what is between the outside of the house and framing. My old house had about 1.5" of insulation board under the siding etc. I never used the silicone but that is a good idea, I will copy it next time.